# function that takes an array as its first argument and a function as a second

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

I have to write the function that takes the array as its first argument and a function as a second. So it should return true only when the predicate returns true for all elements of the array. I've written two functions: "every" which takes an array and another function called "isOne" (which detects if a certain element is equal to one or not), but for some reason it doesn't work. Please, help me to find where's the problem.

```
let someArray = [1,1,1];

function every(array, someFunction) {
  var i = 0;
  var element = array[i];
  while (i < array.length) {
    if (someFunction == false) {
        return false;
        break;
    }
    else {
        return true;
        i++;
    }
  }
}

function ifOne (element) {
    if (element !== 1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

console.log(every(someArray, ifOne()));
```

Comment: kindly check that are you passing second argument as function or not?

Comment: Yes, I want to  pass the second argument as a function

Comment: there's a lot of things wrong with this, 1. you're not passing in a function, 2. you're not calling `someFunction`, 3. you need to return true only when all elements pass

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code to following

- Pass function and not its response - `every(someArray, ifOne)`
- Call function and compare its response - `someFunction(element) == false`
- With `var element = array[i]` outside the loop will never change the value on iteration, hence, to get the correct value move it inside loop.
- Create a `true` return variable and set it to false for **falsy** condition and break the loop.
- Also for false value, you can update the if condition to `if (!someFunction(element))`. Please note, this is not a mandatory update, you can skip it.

```js
let someArray = [1, 1, 1];

function every(array, someFunction) {
  var i = 0;
  var result = true;
  while (i < array.length) {
    var element = array[i];
    if (!someFunction(element)) {
      result = false;
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return result;
}

function ifOne(element) {
  if (element !== 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(every(someArray, ifOne));
```

Please note, you can also simplify your code as following

```js
let someArray = [1,1,1];

function every(array, someFunction) {
  return array.every(v => someFunction(v));
}

function ifOne (element) {
    return element === 1;
}

console.log(every(someArray, ifOne));
```

Comment: I wonder why your first unsimplified code doesn't work (because it returns "true" while for example, someArray = [1,2,1]), while the simplified one works.

Comment: @lashamerebashvili: It's because the loop never changes the value of `element` (it's always `array[i]` as assigned outside the loop from when `i` was `0`; changing `i` doesn't retroactively change `element` to reference a different element in `array`). Your original code has the same problem.

Comment: Hello. I never checked the logic in original code and hence did not noticed the issues in that. ShadowRanger has correctly pointed out the mistake.  I will provide the updated correction for the original code when I am back.

Comment: then what should I do in order to change element?

Comment: @lashamerebashvili - Please see the updated code for explanation.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal  Now I understand what was my mistake, but I am really interested, why "return true & return false" does not work, while "result = true & result = false" works perfectly, can you explain it to me?

Comment: When in a loop, you check against a value, in an if else condition, one of the condition will be true and it will be returned either true or false based on that and any further values in the array will be ignored. Hence, to check for the whole set, you need to set a variable and then check for false condition only. And when a false condition is encountered, set the result to false and break the loop to avoid check for further values.

Comment: @lashamerebashvili - Glad to help you :)